# React Native Font Not Working on iOS when using Native Base

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I followed the steps provided here to install the fonts correctly.
https://docs.nativebase.io/customizing-fonts

When using custom font family/variant let's say "Roboto-Bold", it doesn't seem to reflect or apply. The text doesn't seem to be in bold. It's still looks regular. I don't get any errors though as I have installed the font correctly.

```
import { Text } from 'native-base';


const Component = () => {
  // This doesn't show as bold
  return <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold' }}>Hello world</Text>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the `<Text>` component from 'react-native'; to see if the result is the same and it did work.

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';


const Component = () => {
  // This does show as bold now as intended and being displayed correctly. However, my goals is to use the <Text> component from native-base to make it comp[atible on web for cross-platform compatibility
  return <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold' }}>Hello world</Text>;
};
```

After some trial and error, I tried adding the `fontWeight: undefined` and it worked when using the Text component from the native-base

```
import { Text } from 'native-base';


const Component = () => {
  // This does show as bold now as intended and being displayed correctly
  return <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold', fontWeight: undefined }}>Hello world</Text>;
};
```